# Create and Add Images to Products using Image Data

Tags: magento2, product-images, catalog

How can I create and attach images to products in Magento2?
I have an Image base64 encoded body, name, extension, and mime type. Basically, all the required info to create an image.  Also, note that I want to keep the old images.

Thanks!!